# Lodash does not work in testing environment

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, lodash, karma-webpack

I've got a problem with importing lodash into my testing environment. I'm testing service which uses lodash. In test suite I imported lodash this way:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Then in test I'm able to execute successfully:

```
console.log('lodash version:', _.VERSION);
```

But when I run service method, which uses lodash - I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

How is it possible?

karma.config.js:

```
files: [
  { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false },
  'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'
],
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the service method that you are testing using a "_" defined globally or perhaps imports it's own , overwriting your '_' with undefined (for whatever reason) ?

Comment: It imports lodash by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just import lodash in to your components or services as below and don't do anything apart from it

> import * as _ from "lodash";